# NextJs: set status code 404 without redirection

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to resolve a specific requirement for our web app.
We have a page 'Item' that in case of an item sold out should keep showing item but the page's response code must be set to 404.
I'm trying something like that:

in pages/[id]/Item.tsx:

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
   //retrieve item
   if (item.isSoldOut) {
       ctx.res.statusCode = 404;
   }
   //all other stuff
}
```

but it will automatically redirect to the homepage with status code 302.
How to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next.js documetation suggest to use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` instead of `getInitialProps` (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)

Using `getServerSideProps` you can do as follow

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    return { props: {} }
}
```

Using `getInitialProps` you can do as follow :

```
static async getInitialProps({res}) {
    // server side
    if(res) res.statusCode = 404;

    // client side
    return { statusCode : 404 }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference with my code? (using getInitialProps)

Comment: No differences, in `getIntialProps` implementation the return will pass the `statusCode` to client side (I try this implmentation and it works without redirect). I suggest to use the `getServerSide` implementation.

Comment: returning statusCode will only add to props, no use, but you are right, by default it doesn't redirect. There is something in our app that does it but I can't find

Comment: have you checked if you have some error handler  with redirect in `_app.tsx` or `_document.tsx` ?

Comment: Sorry for bothered you... I couldn't find because there isn't any redirect on app, it's web server that do it :-(